# Exe crashes after coming out of the method in c++

Tags: c++, c, methods, callback

I have a method `FormatOutPut()` that internally calls a "callBack" method `MyFunct()` in C++. There is a crash, when the control comes out the `FormatOutPut()`. The callback method `MyFunct()` just prints the output on the screen. When I debugged the code using windbg I got the following traces,

```
(1250.1270): Stack buffer overflow - code c0000409 (!!! second chance !!!)
```

What I am guessing is that,the return address on the stack for the `FormatOutPut()`, is corrupted by the callback method. So when control is shifted back to the calling method it crashes.

When I comment out the callback method everything works fine. Any inputs on this will be great help.

Callback method prototype is as below,

```
typedef void(__stdcall *MyCallBack)(char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,int, int );
```

Body:-

```
void MyCallbackRoutine(char* GetFeature,char* GetVersion,char* GetStartDate, char* GetExpireDate, char* GetUsers,char* GetKey,char* GetVendorString, char* GetHostID,char* GetErrorMsg,char* GetLicense,int GetCheckOutStatus, int nCount)     
{
        if ( nCount == 0 )    
        {  

            _strtime_s( timeCallbackstart, 10 );

            time(&startCallbackstart);   

            bOnlyOnce = true;    
        }    
    cout << endl;    
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------" << endl;    
    cout << "GetCheckOutStatus: " << GetCheckOutStatus << endl;     
    cout << "GetErrorMsg:       " << GetErrorMsg << endl;     
    cout << endl;    
    cout << "GetFeature:        " << GetFeature << endl;    
    cout << "GetVersion:        " << GetVersion << endl;     
    cout << "GetStartDate:      " << GetStartDate  << endl;     
    cout << "GetExpireDate:     " << GetExpireDate << endl;     
    cout << "GetUsers:          " << GetUsers << endl;     
    cout << "GetKey:            " << GetKey << endl;     
    cout << "GetVendorString:   " << GetVendorString << endl;     
    cout << "GetHostID:         " << GetHostID << endl;     
    cout << "GetLicense:        " << GetLicense << endl;     
    cout << endl;    
    cout << "Licenscounter:     " << nCount << endl;     
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << endl;    
    cout << endl;

}
```

Thanks and Regards,
AKJ

Comment: I would hate to be the programmer who has to call such a function.  Twelve parameters, with 10 being character pointers.  Yikes.

Comment: Even I hate :P.. This code was working fine when compiled with VS2008 compiler on win7 OS. I am facing problem when I use VS2013 and win10 OS.

Comment: So you posted a callback prototype.  What information are we to extract from this, except that it has an awful lot of parameters?  How about posting what this callback is calling?  Instead of commenting out the call, comment out the body of the callback function itself and just have a `return` statement.  If the error goes away, then it is something you're doing in that function that is at fault.  If the error still persists, then it has something to do with (more than likely) a calling convention mismatch or parameter mismatch.

Comment: void MyCallbackRoutine(char* GetFeature, char* GetVersion,char* GetStartDate, char* GetEndDate, char* GetUsers, char* GetK, char* GetVString, char* GetHostID, char* GetErrorMsg, char* GetAllString,int GetStatus, int nCount)
   { if ( nCount == 0 )
      {_strtime_s( timeCallbackstart, 10 );
       time(&startCallbackstart);
       bOnlyOnce = true;}
    cout<<"------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"GetCheckOutStatus"<<GetStatus<<endl; 
    cout<<"GetErrorMsg:"<<GetErrorMsg<<ndl; 
    cott<<"GetFeature:"<<GetFeature<<endl;
    cout<<"GetVersion:"<<GetVersion<<endl;

Comment: continu....  cout<<"GetStartDate:"<<GetStartDate<<endl; 
    cout<<"GetExpireDate:"<<GetEndDate<<endl; 
    cout<<"GetUsers:"<<GetUsers<< endl; 
    cout<<"GetKey:"<<GetK<<endl; 
    cout<<"GetVendorString:"<<GetString<<endl; 
    cout<<"GetHostID:"<<GetHostID<<endl; 
    cout<<"GetLicense:"<<GetAllString<<endl; 
    cout<<"Licenscounter:"<<nCount<< endl; 
    cout<<"-----" << endl;}

Comment: I commented out body of the callback method, but I am still facing the same crash...:(

Comment: @AKJ please edit your question with the function definition you have provided in comments. It will be more readable and you can expect more answers.

Comment: If the program is crashing right when you try to return from a function, you probably double freed a pointer somewhere, or you went out-of-bounds somewhere. The code where this happened doesn't have to have anything to do with the code that's crashing. You should use a heap debugger such as Valgrind. If you're sure it's the callback, disassemble it and see whether the return pointer is changing during its execution.

Comment: If I am not wrong valgrind is supported in linux. Can you please suggest any tool for windows OS.

Comment: @AKJ You specified the  `__stdcall` calling convention on the callback prototype, but the function you posted in your comments (please put it in the original post) doesn't show that this calling convention is used.  By default, C++ programs use the `__cdecl` calling convention, not `__stdcall`.  A calling convention mismatch can cause crashes (usually stack based, but usually not an overflow issue).

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, but unfortunately even after using __cdecl instead of __stdcall, the crash still persists.

Comment: @AKJ The calling conventions **must** match.  Even if it doesn't fix your immediate issue, that is just one thing that has to be done.  What you posted is clearly wrong if you've got a `__stdcall` function definition, and assigning it a `__cdecl` function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, please give some example snippet.

Comment: Unless `timeCallbackstart` is < 10 bytes long, startCallbackstart is not large enough to receive a time_t, or one of your char* pointers is not null terminated, then this code has nothing to do with your crash.

Comment: @AJK [Look here](http://rextester.com/SCKF85536) -- The code you posted shouldn't have even compiled if you have a mismatch calling convention.  I am wondering now what your real code is like, as certainly the example at the link shows you cannot assign that function to the prototype you posted.

Comment: @AKJ [Here is the correction](http://rextester.com/EPM40475)  Compiles cleanly, and no crash.  Did your code apply an ill-advised cast to get the compiler to shut up about the compiler error?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thank you. Your suggestion worked. Crash is not seen now. But now I have to check why the compiler didn't give me any warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that I see is that your calling convention of `__stdcall` for the `typedef` of the function prototype and the callback function itself does not match.  If the calling convention does not match up, stack issues can arise when returning from the called function.

More on [calling conventions here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

The `typedef` for the function is as follows:

```
typedef void(__stdcall *MyCallBack)(char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,
                                    char*,char*,char*,int, int );
```

but the function that is assigned as the callback has this:

```
void MyCallbackRoutine(char* GetFeature,char* GetVersion,char* GetStartDate, 
                       char* GetExpireDate, char* GetUsers,char* GetKey,
                       char* GetVendorString, char* GetHostID,
                       char* GetErrorMsg,char* GetLicense,
                       int GetCheckOutStatus, int nCount)
```

The number and type of parameters match up, the return type `void` matches, but the key element that doesn't match is that `__stdcall` is missing.  By default, The calling convention is `__cdecl` if not specified.  The correction should be:

```
void __stdcall MyCallbackRoutine(char* GetFeature,char* GetVersion,char* GetStartDate, 
                       char* GetExpireDate, char* GetUsers,char* GetKey,
                       char* GetVendorString, char* GetHostID,
                       char* GetErrorMsg,char* GetLicense,
                       int GetCheckOutStatus, int nCount)
```

Note that the compiler should have picked up the issue when assigning a function who's definition doesn't match the prototype as [this small example](http://rextester.com/SCKF85536) demonstrates  (If this compiler error occurs, do not try to fix it by applying a `C`-style cast to shut the compiler up -- that is not a fix).